# PHP Regex replace multiple urls with itself with a return function

Tags: php, preg-replace, backend, preg-replace-callback

I have a site where I need to check and replace a text with href's in it, that's not the problem. But I have to localize the url, that's done with a function, but I can't get it to work together.

My code to replace the links:

```
$text = "this is a test text blabla <a href="https://example.com/test/">Test</a>";
$pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))+/";
$replace = '${0}';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

I need to do the localize function over the $replace variable when I'm replacing the text. I know it can be done by using preg_replace_callback, I searched the internet but can't get it working.

My code to localize the url:

```
$replace = WPGlobus_Utils::localize_url($replace, 'en');
// This will replace the url from https://example.com/test/ to https://example.com/en/test/
```

Thanks in advance,

Remy

Comment: So after the TLD you need to add `en/`?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the problem. I first have to preg_replace all links in a string, and I need to localize (add en/ to the url) after the preg is going to be replaced.

Comment: 1) Use `$pattern = "/(?<=href=[\"'])[^\"']+(?=[\"'])/";` pattern 2) `preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) { return localize_url($m[0]);}, $text);` or something like that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I edited the code a bit and it worked great! :)

Comment: My last today's vote goes for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with the following slightly enhanced pattern:

```
$pattern = "/(?<=href=[\"'])[^\"']+(?=[\"'])/";
```

And then...

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) { 
   return localize_url($m[0]);
}, $text);
```

Note that `(\"|')` is meant to match either `"` or `'` and it is much better and efficient to use a character class instead, that is `["']`.